# Save touch point location coordinates

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

I have `UIWebView` for displays `HTML` article pages. I used UILongPressGesture for getting touch location coordinates. I need to save this coordinates to NSUserDefaults or anywhere and get it later for another use. How to save these touch location coordinates

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTest:)];
    [tap setDelegate:self];
    [wbCont.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}


- (void)tapTest:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"coordinate is %f %f", [sender locationInView:wbCont].x,  [sender locationInView:wbCont].y);

}


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: then what is your problem ??

Comment: These two [sender locationInView:wbCont].x,  [sender locationInView:wbCont].y displays x & y coordinates. How to save this coordinate and get later or how to use these coordinate later use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For store location in  `NSUserDefaults`

```
  - (void)tapTest:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender 
    {
        NSLog(@"coordinate is %f %f", [sender locationInView:wbCont].x,  [sender locationInView:wbCont].y);

    CGFloat x = [sender locationInView:wbCont].x;
    CGFloat y = [sender locationInView:wbCont].Y;

      NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      [userDefaults setFloat:x forKey:@"xPoint"];
      [userDefaults setFloat:y forKey:@"yPoint"];
      [userDefaults synchronize];

    }
```

And retrieve point from `NSUserDefaults`

```
NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
float xValue = [data floatForKey:@"xPoint"];
float yValue = [data floatForKey:@"yPoint"];
```

Comment: use simple float instead of CGFloat

Comment: @iPatel CGFloat is just a typedef around float, in the same way that NSInteger is a typedef around int. It's a good idea to to use CGFloat and NSInteger now that iOS supports 32 and 64-bit processors.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from user defaults as well for future use.

```
 -(void)tapTest:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
 {
  NSLog(@"coordinate is %f %f", [sender locationInView:wbCont].x,  [sender locationInView:wbCont].y);

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:[sender locationInView:wbCont].x forKey:@"xCor"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:[sender locationInView:wbCont].y forKey:@"yCor"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

  }
```